# How can I programatically show/hide editLink client side in Vuepress 2?

Tags: vuepress

I want to show the edit link only for privileged users. I have user information that I am using for example for routing, and I can use it in components. However, I have not found any way to show/hide the edit link on each page based on the user roles. It must be done client side. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:

1. Follow the [instructions](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/advanced/cookbook/extending-a-theme.html#extend-default-theme) to extend the default theme.
2. Make your own `EditLink` component like this:

```js
// EditLink.vue
<template></template>
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { usePageFrontmatter } from "@vuepress/client";

onMounted(() => {
  const fm = usePageFrontmatter();
  fm.value.editLink = true; // Replace true with your logic
});
</script>
```

3. In the Layout component (see instructions linked above) do this:

```js
// Layout.vue
<template>
  <Layout>
    <template #page-bottom> <EditLink /></template>
  </Layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import Layout from "@vuepress/theme-default/lib/client/layouts/Layout.vue";
import EditLink from "../components/EditLink";
</script>
```